# How to execute shell some query in Rockmongo or mongovue?

Tags: mongodb

I executed a command in mongo.exe. Let's try with the most basic command.

```
> db.tablebusiness.find({"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"});
```

I got results:

Now I try similar command in rockmongo.
If I execute

```
db.tablebusiness.find(
    {"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
    );
```

Result:

```
{
   "retval": null,
   "ok": 1
}
```

Basically it seems to tell me that the result is ok or something like that? I am not sure.

If I elaborate:

```
var cur = db.tablebusiness.find(
{"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
);
cur.forEach(function(x){print(tojson(x))});
```

Result:

```
{
   "retval": null,
   "ok": 1
}
```

Same problem.

If I do:

```
function () {
   return db.tablebusiness.find({"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"});
}
```

I got:

```
 {
   "retval": {
     "value": "DBQuery: hello.tablebusiness -> undefined"
  },
   "ok": 1
}
```

What does it mean by hello.tablebusiness -> undefined is beyond me. As you see from above, I successfully execute the query just fine in mongo.exe

Looks like rockmongo has very limited feature. I wonder how to actually see result. How to execute random mongodb command in rockmongo and observe the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I agree with you: rockmongo has very limited feature at the moment.
I use it for simple queries because allows me access to my remote server from any browsing enabled device.

The "execute" area in rockmongo run with ["Javascript API"](http://api.mongodb.org/js/) and not behave like the mongo shell.

Try this:

```
function () {
    var cur = db.tablebusiness.find(
    {"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
    );
    var out = [];
    cur.forEach(function(x){out.push(x);});
    return(out);
}
```

You can run simple queries clicking on the collection name, typing your query condition in the upper area...

```
 {"_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"}
```

...and then "submit query"

Comment: Thanks! I was confused about this too, but now I see find() is returning some sort of cursor object you have to iterate over. Kind of a pain, but I can work with it now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer - that might seem a little strange - is to use the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, but only pipeline in a single [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) command, like so:

```
function () {
  return db.tablebusiness.aggregate([
    { $match: {
      "_id": "the-simmons-paradise__41.85_-87.88"
    }}
  ]);
}
```